# Don't want box-shadow appears above nav

Tags: html, css

Here is the demo: [Here it is](https://codepen.io/bidiajin/pen/mRJdzq)

I don't want to put the shadow above the `<nav>` but do want to put the shadow above the `<footer>`

```css
nav{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
main{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: #555555;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
footer{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
footer > a,
#parent{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<main></main>
<footer>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="parent">
      This is link
    </div>
  </a>
</footer>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry i'm new in here, and this is my first question

Comment: Next time make sure to add your code within your question rather than linking to an external site.

Comment: Yea, that's fine. Nothing to be sorry for.

Comment: Can you describe your problem more clearly? Perhaps an image showing the desired result?

Comment: @PraveenKumar okay

Comment: @Turnip I want to remove the shadow from `nav`

Comment: `nav` doesn't have a `box-shadow`. Do you actually want the `main` `box-shadow` to be _behind_ `nav`?

Comment: @Turnip yeah, the ordering or Levels of a tag is necessary in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` and a `z-index` value to your `nav` to pull it above the `main` element.

```css
nav{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
main{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: #555555;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
footer{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
footer > a,
#parent{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<main></main>
<footer>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="parent">
      This is link
    </div>
  </a>
</footer>
```

Comment: works perfectly and properly :D
thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

put `box-shadow: 0px 16px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);` insted of `box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);`

Comment: thanks dude, it works actually.